# Conditional average of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, worksheet-function

I would like the average of a subset of values within a column in an Excel spreadsheet. For example, just those in the value range `10` to `11` within ColumnA containing many values. The result should be in a different column.

Comment: Are you sure you need VBA for this? If you want the result to be in the same workbook then you could probably use the AVERAGEIF or AVERAGEIFS function.

Comment: Microsoft explain it better than I could, see here: [AVERAGEIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx)
and here: [AVERAGEIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageifs-function-HA010047493.aspx)

Comment: The new column should have just the average. Column A has many values I just want the ones that range from 10-11

Comment: @Joe, I'm using the AverageIf function but am unsure how to output the value. I have so far: 

Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(range("A1:A2"),"3612783503.166")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you want (if a formula suits) is:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,A:A,">="&10,A:A,"<="&11)
```